# Sending an email after 7 minutes of recording record to SQL DB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using asp.net with vb.net..
I need to send an email to my website visitor after they signup to db ..
or by another way 
I need to do any action after inserting record to SQL db.
Example

```
Dim Visitor as new Visitor
Visitor.Name = "#######"
Visitor.Email = "###@####.com
Visitor.Save()
```

I need to wait here for example 7 minutes then

```
SendEmail()
```

Is there any way to wait this minutes before I send the email.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about if your visitor leaves the site? The program execution would stop and therefore there would be no way to count the time.

Maybe you could create a schedule task running an external app that monitors new signups every minute, for example; if a given sign-up is older than 7 minutes, then send email.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a scheduled job that runs every few minutes and sends out emails perhaps.